# AngularJS filter exact values with length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

What I want to do is count the filter length of an array of objects by a particular property based on the repeater scope. This code technically works (it displays the correct count of the filter):

```
<li ng-repeat="question in questions" id="{{ question.id }}">
    {{ question.text }}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" id="{{ answer.id }}">
            {{ answer.text }} (<span ng-controller='AnswersController'>{{ (useranswers|filter:{answer_id:answer.id}).length }}</span>)
         </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

The problem is, when scope ID is `1` (for example), it matches on `1`,`10`,`11`,`21`, etc. I'd like to make the exact code I have above work on an exact match.

Please let me know what supporting code would be helpful.

Comment: Where is the comparison code here?  I might be missing something (probably) but I don't see where you say x.indexOf(y)==-1 or x==y or x===y anything of this nature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to say to Angular that you want a strict comparaison. That's easy to do with Angular 1.1.5, because the filter `filter` (see the [documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.filter:filter)) has now a third parameter, `comparator`, where `true` is a very usefull shorthand. In your case, you can simply make something like that :

```
<li ng-repeat="question in questions" id="{{ question.id }}">
    {{ question.text }}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" id="{{ answer.id }}">
            {{ answer.text }} (<span ng-controller='AnswersController'>{{ (useranswers|filter:{answer_id:answer.id}:true).length }}</span>)
         </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```